# Adding Routes for WebAPI in MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-routing

I've got a WebApi Controller and want to add a route.

Here is my Controller ...

```
        public class ExtraInformationController : ApiController
        {
            private readonly ExtraInformationRepository _extraInfoRepository = new ExtraInformationRepository();

            public ExtraInformation Get(int assetId)
            {
                return _extraInfoRepository.GetByAssetID(assetId).FirstOrDefault();
            }

        }
```

Heres my route ...

```
  routes.MapHttpRoute(
            "ExtraInformation",
            "api/ExtraInformation/{assetId}",
            new { controller = "ExtraInformation", action = "Get" }
        );
```

I want to be able to call ...

api/ExtraInformation/4

But I'm getting ...

No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:35188/api/ExtraInformation/4'.No action was found on the controller 'ExtraInformation' that matches the request.

Can anyone assist please?

Comment: Why don't you just rename your parameter to `id`?

Comment: You don't need to specify the "action" parameter if your action is called `Get`. Web API will invoke this automatically based on the HTTP method used. Also, you need to make sure this route is registered before the default API route.

Comment: Felipe - because it's not the primary key (id) that I want to use for the get - it's a foreign key (assetId)

Answer (score 0):

Using the generic default route should be enough looking at your example.  I would swap it for this and give it a try.

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```